# How to find a "(a substring)" in a given "text" without using Regular expressions?

Tags: javascript

Recently I was asked in an interview, where the interviewer asked me this above question.

I was surely perplexed and answered him by using a for loop implementation where

1. we would find the length of the given "text" (using JavaScript) ... `str.length()` ...
2. we would take the first element of the "pattern" and find that in the "text".
3. If found we would increment the array .. As strings are stored as array in JavaScript ..
4. And we would find the "(a substring)" in similar way..

know this might be wrong way , but can anyone suggest a better way ? Thank you :-)

Comment: [`string.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Internally, I would suspect that is what's happening. How else can you find a pattern in a given set of text without iterating over the characters. If the pattern is simple, you can use some type of `contains` or `indexOf` function.

Comment: He said write a code for Regular Expression itself .. Means to write a code for str.match() .. Using no inbuilt function .. Make your own function

Comment: There is a difference between a pattern and a substring. You question is not fully accurate

Comment: @arty .. Corrected it :-)

Comment: He surely wasn't asking you to write `RegExp` from scratch? And why `str.match`, why not [`str.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)? Your question is highly unclear. Pattern or substring?

Comment: @Xotic750 he said do not use any functions :( ..

Comment: Write it in pseudocode. Did he specify a language?

Comment: Yeah i explained him the pseudocode and i think he was little bit happy with it ..but he surely wanted me to code .. P.S. it was an interview for FB internship .. So i was panicking

Comment: Because if someone knows a code in c++ .. I would be able to understand that too .. @codah :-)

Comment: @Xotic750 he did not specify any language

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter Then surely `str.find()` would do the job in C++? If it's a substring not a pattern, then all the regex talk is moot? You didn't say whether to find the first only or all substrings.

Comment: @Xotic750 - "did he specify a language" - the original question used PHP and JavaScript tags. I'm not sure why they were removed from the original posting. JavaScript has been re-added since Harshal specifically called it out.

Comment: @noloader No idea what's going on with that. :/

Comment: Perhaps [tag:algorithm] should be added as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer depends on the context, and the context seems to be lacking.

If the question was about algorithms, then I believe your best choice of algorithms (i.e., the fastest algorithm) is [Boyer–Moore string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

If the question was a HowTo in PHP, then its probably `string.indexOf`. And `str.search` would probably not be a valid answer since it takes a regex.

> 1. S[i] refers to the character at index i of string S, counting from 1.
> 2. S[i..j] refers to the substring of string S starting at index i and ending at j, inclusive.
> 3. A prefix of S is a substring S[1..i] for some i in range [1, n], where n is the length of S.
> 4. A suffix of S is a substring S[i..n] for some i in range [1, n], where n is the length of S.
> 5. The string to be searched for is called the pattern and is referred to with symbol P.
> 6. The string being searched in is called the text and is referred to with symbol T.
> 7. The length of P is n.
> 8. The length of T is m.
> 9. An alignment of P to T is an index k in T such that the last character of P is aligned with index k of T.
> 10. A match or occurrence of P occurs at an alignment if P is equivalent to T[(k-n+1)..k].

Comment: I had to use NO functions !!:( ..  Just basic for loop and something like that ..

Comment: Your question does not state "NO functions". It only states "without using regular expressions" (and that's in the title). But you still have the Boyer-Moore string search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

> [String.prototype.search (regexp)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.12)
>
> When the search method is called with argument regexp, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Call CheckObjectCoercible passing the this value as its argument.
> 2. Let string be the result of calling ToString, giving it the this value as its argument.
> 3. If Type(regexp) is Object and the value of the [[Class]] internal property of regexp is "RegExp", then let rx be regexp;
> 4. Else, let rx be a new RegExp object created as if by the expression new RegExp(regexp) where RegExp is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 5. Search the value string from its beginning for an occurrence of the regular expression pattern rx. Let result be a Number indicating the offset within string where the pattern matched, or –1 if there was no match. The lastIndex and global properties of regexp are ignored when performing the search. The lastIndex property of regexp is left unchanged.
> 6. Return result.

Or if you want to avoid the word `RegExp` alltogether and search for a sub-string then

> [String.prototype.indexOf (searchString, position)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.7)
>
> If searchString appears as a substring of the result of converting this object to a String, at one or more positions that are greater than or equal to position, then the index of the smallest such position is returned; otherwise, ‑1 is returned. If position is undefined, 0 is assumed, so as to search all of the String.
>
> The indexOf method takes two arguments, searchString and position, and performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Call CheckObjectCoercible passing the this value as its argument.
> 2. Let S be the result of calling ToString, giving it the this value as its argument.
> 3. Let searchStr be ToString(searchString).
> 4. Let pos be ToInteger(position). (If position is undefined, this step produces the value 0).
> 5. Let len be the number of characters in S.
> 6. Let start be min(max(pos, 0), len).
> 7. Let searchLen be the number of characters in searchStr.
> 8. Return the smallest possible integer k not smaller than start such that k+ searchLen is not greater than len, and for all nonnegative integers j less than searchLen, the character at position k+j of S is the same as the character at position j of searchStr; but if there is no such integer k, then return the value -1.